# SQL server 2008 - SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can someone please help me with the below script? I to know how to return the value for the calculation 500*@point_rate. I'm getting the following error message

> Msg 235, Level 16, State 0, Line 18
>   Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

Script:

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @POINT_RATE MONEY
SET @POINT_RATE = 0.05          


SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SET @SCRIPT = "SELECT 500*'"+ @POINT_RATE + "'"

PRINT @SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `CAST` it to `VARCHAR`.

Something like

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @POINT_RATE MONEY
SET @POINT_RATE = 0.05          


SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SET @SCRIPT = "SELECT 500*"+ CAST(@POINT_RATE AS VARCHAR(10))

PRINT @SCRIPT
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at my question. I actually need the "@point_rate" within the "", this isn't all of the script, but I'm only having trouble with this section of the script.

Comment: You can leave it in the quotes if you wish, you just need to `CAST` it to `VARCHAR` to work